# Update an excel file, append new rows to a specific sheet in an excel file, python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, xlsxwriter

so i have a list of dicts of no matching key:

```
list = [{'name': 'abc', 'link': 'google.com'}, {'name': 'vba', 'link': 'google.com', 'age': 23}]
```

and i want to check an excel file with multiple sheets if the names in the list exist in any rows in the sheets, and save the dictionaries that are new based on the name key comparison.

problem is i get a new excel file with the only modified sheet, and all other sheets are deleted.

whats causing this issue and how to solve it ?

many thanks.

code:

```
def updater(data, filename, sheet_name, column_name, key):
    # Load the existing data from the Excel file
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Create a set of existing values for the specified column for quick lookup
    existing_values = set(df[column_name].values)

    # Filter the data for dictionaries with no matching values
    new_dicts = [d for d in data if d[key] not in existing_values]

    # Append the new dictionaries to the DataFrame
    new_rows = pd.DataFrame(new_dicts)
    df = df._append(new_rows, ignore_index=True)

    # Save the updated DataFrame to the Excel file
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

    print(len(new_dicts), new_dicts)
    print(f"[INFO] Data added to the Excel file successfully.")
```

the excel sheets all have a name column, which i need to compare with name key in the dicts.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the excel file since you're writing DataFrame back to it. Rather than only using pandas for modification operations, I would recommend using openpyxl

> pip install openpyxl

```
def updater(data, filename, sheet_name, column_name, key):
    # Load the existing data from the Excel file
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

    # Use pd.ExcelFile to read all sheets
    with pd.ExcelFile(filename, engine='openpyxl') as xls:
    df_dict = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=None)
    if sheet_name in df_dict:
        df = df_dict[sheet_name]
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Create a set of existing values for the specified column for quick lookup
    existing_values = set(df[column_name].values)

    # Filter the data for dictionaries with no matching values
    new_dicts = [d for d in data if d[key] not in existing_values]

    # Append the new dictionaries to the DataFrame
    new_rows = pd.DataFrame(new_dicts)
    df = df.append(new_rows, ignore_index=True)

    # Save the updated DataFrame to the Excel file
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}

        for sheet, frame in df_dict.items():
            if sheet != sheet_name:
                frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

    print(len(new_dicts), new_dicts)
    print(f"[INFO] Data added to the Excel file successfully.")here
```

Comment: i am getting this error:     writer.book = book
AttributeError: can't set attribute, which raise an other exception at df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False) IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible

Comment: make sure your file permissions allow editing, have an excel tab with the same name, and do not have the excel file open while running

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that is much closer to your original one:

```py
def updater(data, filename, sheet_name, column_name, key):
    # Load the existing data from the Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)

    # Create a set of existing values for the specified column for quick lookup
    existing_values = set(df[column_name].values)

    # Filter the data for dictionaries with no matching values
    new_dicts = [d for d in data if d[key] not in existing_values]

    # Append the new dictionaries to the DataFrame
    new_rows = pd.DataFrame(new_dicts)
    df = pd.concat([df, new_rows], ignore_index=True)

    # Save the updated DataFrame to the Excel file
    with pd.ExcelWriter(
        filename, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay', engine='openpyxl'
    ) as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

Some comments:

- As in the other answer the `engine` used for writing is `openpyxl`.
- I've made the following adjustments:

  - Removed the `try`-`except`-block because the the following part can't deal with an empty dataframe: `df[column_name].values` won't work it that case.
  - Replaced `df._append` with `pd.concat` (because `_append` shouldn't be used).
  - Created a `writer` with the `mode='a'` and `if_sheet_exists='overlay'` (and, as already mentioned, with `engine='openpyxl'`): this setting makes sure that the existing sheet doesn't cause any problem. The default is `if_sheet_exists='error'`, which raises an error if a sheet with name `sheet_name` already exists. The option `'overlay'` is fine since you are only adding new rows.

If you want to keep the `try`-`except`-block then I think this would be the replacement that fits your intent:

```py
...
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=None)
        return
...
```

This writes the the full data into a new excel file which is in line with the logic to add the data that don't exist (all here).